# Почему событие не всплывает в данном случае?

Tags: jquery, события, lightbox

```
    $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
        return false;
      });
```

`$lightbox = $('#lightbox');` - это родитель элемента `.lb-outerContainer`. Если я правильно понимаю, то "клик" должен подняться вверх по `DOM`, найти элемент `#lightbox` и выполнить клик на нем. (сработает проверка `if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();` и выполниться метод `.end()` ). Но так не происходит. Может кто объяснит почему?

Html там такой.

[image].

Comment: ошибок никаких в консоли нету?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так сделайте,

```
  $lightbox.on('click','.lb-outerContainer', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
    return false;
  });
```

это повесит событие на $lightbox, оно вызовет ваш обработчик.

Comment: [вот этот код ?](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/js/lightbox.js#L136) жуть, не пользуйтесь этим ссылаться в плагинах на id... это надо додуматься

Answer (score 0):

А почему вы решили что должен? Клик придёт в лайтбокс, но на его клик нет обработчика.. обработчик сработает для outerContainer'а, но будет отклонён.. и всё.. второй раз вызван не будет.

Comment: cy6erGn0m, это не мой код. это кусочек кода из плагина lightbox2, я пытаюсь понять зачем автор это написал...

Comment: На "#lightbox"-е есть обработчик - $lightbox.hide().on('click', function(e) {
if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
return false;
});  Скорее всего мне кажется что автор рассчитывал что оно будет работать так, но почему оно не работает...